# only the first line of my javascript code works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used some code to fill my inputs bij an onclick function. Now the first line works but it seems that he skips the other lines what can I do?.

This is my code:

```
var InputProduct = document.getElementById("product");
var InputNaam = document.getElementById("Anaam");
var InputPrijs = document.getElementById("APrijs");
var InputVolgorde = document.getElementById("AvolgNR");


function fill($name, $prijs , $volgorde)
{
    InputProduct.value = $name;
     InputNaam.value = $name;
      InputPrijs.value = $prijs;
       InputVolgorde.value = $volgorde; 
}
```

and this is how i use the onclick:

```
onclick="fill('<?php echo $adviesprijzen['Naam']; ?>', '<?php echo $adviesprijzen['BedragInclBTW']; ?>', '<?php echo $adviesprijzen['volgorde']; ?>')"
```

Comment: What element types are the 3 failing items?  Are there errors in the console?

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: you must be getting `undefined` for `document.getElementById("Anaam")`. Hence code execution is not proceeding further beyond the line `InputNaam.value = $name;` . Please make sure that you provided correct `id` in each statement.

Comment: code worked when i created a `test.php` with the above code like this:-https://eval.in/807697  (check code not output) (at my local end) so it seems that `document.getElementById("Anaam")` and so on others are undefined

Comment: thanks fot the replies, my consol did not give an error so thats why i put up this question. howevers after uploading it again it apeared to be working so the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working again after re-uploading the files.